# Synchronous access to queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement where I will hit a link and get a response. The response is an XML data containing child links. The response is then copied to a file and the child links are added to a queue where I then iteratively have to hit the child links until there are no further childs.

I first did this using a single queue. But since it was slow, I tried to implement an executor. I do not have to maintain the order of the data. This is my approach now :

```
 public class Hierarchy2 {

    private static AbstractQueue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private static FileWriter writer;

    private static SAXParser saxParser;
    private static XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        writer = new FileWriter(new File("hierarchy.txt"));
        String baseUrl = "my url here";

        queue.add(baseUrl);

        int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            executor.execute(new QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler));
        }

        executor.shutdown();

    }
}

class QueueProcess implements Runnable {

    private AbstractQueue<String> queue;
    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private URL url;
    private FileWriter writer;
    private SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    private SAXParser saxParser;
    private XMLHandler xmlHandler;

    public QueueProcess(AbstractQueue<String> queue, FileWriter writer, XMLHandler xmlHandler) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.writer = writer;

        this.xmlHandler = xmlHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            while (true) {
                String link = queue.poll();
                if (link != null) {
                    if (queue.size() >= 500) {
                        System.out.println("here" + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        getChildLinks(link);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(link + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        queue.addAll(getChildLinks(link));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private List<String> getChildLinks(String link) throws IOException, SAXException {
        url = new URL(link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())).lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        saxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()), xmlHandler);
        List<String> urlList = xmlHandler.getURLList();

        writer.write(result + System.lineSeparator());

        connection.disconnect();
        return urlList;
    }

}
```

The program runs fine but at some point I am getting a null pointer exception . It is on the `queue.addAll` line in the `QueueProcess'` `run` method.

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.checkNotNull(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:914)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.addAll(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:525)
    at QueueProcess.run(Hierarchy2.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.checkNotNull(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:914)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.addAll(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:525)
    at QueueProcess.run(Hierarchy2.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't figure out why there is a NPE since I check if the queue is not empty before for every iteration of the while loop. Please tell me why do I get a null pointer exception and can prevent this from happening.

**Update:**

I've finally fixed the NPE. As suggested by *@gusto2* , it was due to the arraylist containing an null value which the queue does not accept.

Now my code it like this :

```
public class Hierarchy2 {

    private static BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static FileWriter writer;
    private static XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        writer = new FileWriter(new File("hierarchy.txt"));
        String baseUrl = "my url here";

        queue.add(baseUrl);

        int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            executor.execute(new QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler));
        }

        executor.shutdown();

    }
}

class QueueProcess implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    private HttpURLConnection connection;
    private URL url;
    private FileWriter writer;
    private SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    private SAXParser saxParser;
    private XMLHandler xmlHandler = new XMLHandler();

    public QueueProcess(BlockingQueue<String> queue, FileWriter writer, XMLHandler xmlHandler) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            while (true) {
                String link = queue.poll();
                if (link != null) {
                    System.out.println(link + "     " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    queue.addAll(getChildLinks(link));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private List<String> getChildLinks(String link) throws IOException, SAXException {
        url = new URL(link);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())).lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining());

        saxParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes()), xmlHandler);
        List<String> urlList = xmlHandler.getURLList();

        writer.write(result + System.lineSeparator());

        connection.disconnect();
        return urlList;
    }

}
```

The problem now is to pause the threads when the threads TOGETHER have processed 500 records. Once 500 is reached, I will have to create another file and then start my processing again.

Also please tell me how I can stop the code after all the queues is fully read. ie. no more child links will be added to the queue. Since I am using a always true while loop, the code is going to run indefinitely. If I use the condition `while(!queue.isEmpty())`, only one of the threads will run as other will find the queue empty.

Comment: You're only using a single thread there. After all, you only call `executor.execute()` once. One task, one thread.

Comment: my bad ! edited the question.

Comment: Make use of ForkJoinPool and ForkJoinTask -> RecursiveTask/Action , since i see that this is a recursive/Independent subpart computation. This will allow a clearer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.checkNotNull(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:914) 
at  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.addAll(ConcurrentLinkedQueue.java:525)
```

I'd guess that  `List<String> urlList = xmlHandler.getURLList();` returns an ArrayList with some null values inside. Though without much more information it is hard to tell more precise

Comment: yes ! you are right. I don't know why there is a null value in that list since there will NOT be a way for a null value. I'm checking on that

Comment: `there will NOT be a way for a null value` that's an assumption you need to prove

Comment: I just fixed the null values in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here you add base url only once in queue. It is not in the loop.

```
    queue.add(baseUrl);

    int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        executor.execute(new QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler));
    }
```

So, when you call `QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler)`, you pass a single entry. And then when you call `String link = queue.poll();`, it removes that only one added value. And how can the `queue.size() >= 500` be, if you pass a queue with a single value added in `QueueProcess(queue, writer, xmlHandler)` in for loop?

Comment: "how can the queue.size() >= 500 be.." because  the `QueueProcess` may put mutiple links in the quee. Indeed the program could be done nicer, but that should not cause NPE

Comment: @gusto2 A suggestion of the same in `codereview` is to use two queues, one which hold the links and one the response. But i'm worried about how to make the response queue to wait until the 500 records are loaded to the file.

Comment: @v1shnu For that you could open a new question..though - I'd use a synchronized counter / atomic variable or CountDownLatch. I'd keep it simple and use a counter